# How to convert(not just output) elements of an array into it's hexadecimal values

Tags: c, rijndael

I have to implement Rijndael algorithm in C. I start with this:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int main() {
    int i=0,j;
    char m[5000];
    char message[5000];
    char ch;
    printf("Introduce the message\n\n");
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        message[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    message[i]='\0';
    i=0;
    while(message[i]!='\0')
    {
        sscanf(&message[i],"%x",&m);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nResult\n");
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf(" %x",&m[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I need an array in which for example "Hello"(where array1[0] will show H) will be written as 48656c6c6f, and when calling array2[0] it will show 48.

Comment: You should post your best shot that didn't work properly, together with sample inputs and what you expect to do with them.

Comment: The question "Please give me the solution" is off-topic for stackoverflow. You say something about not being able to "find it's hexadecimal value", but I am unsure what you mean by that. You can cast a char to an int without a problem. An int is a number, and you can interpret that as anything you like, including binary or hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a hexadecimal representation of `message`'s contents? If so, what you need is this:

```
char messageHex[sizeof(message)*2];
memset(messageHex, 0, sizeof(messageHex));
size_t len = strlen(message);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    sprintf(messageHex + i*2, "%02X", message[i] & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: This code populates `messageHex[]` yet has 2 short-comings.  1) No limit to 2 hex characters as in `message[i] = -1; sprintf(messageHex + i*2, "%02X", message[i]);` 2) Last terminating null character is written outside `messageHex[]`.

Comment: @chux 1) Thanks, fixed. 2) I do not believe so, what makes you say that?

Comment: Concerning 2) I incorrectly thought `messageHex[]` was sized to `strlen(message)*2`.

Answer (score 0):

What use would it be to you to make an array that contains the **hexadecimal** value in a **decimal** representation? It's the same numeric value after all.

Printing it would be as simple as `printf("%x\n", arr[0]);`.

If you insist, then you can have an array of strings (`char*`) with each containing the string of the hexadecimal value then you might want to use `sprintf()` (so you won't need to do any calculations yourself) as following:

```
unsigned char** hex_arr = malloc(arrLen); //arrLen is the integer array length
for(i = 0 ; i < arrLen ; i++) //declare i first
{
    hex_arr[i] = malloc(3); //2 characters and null (two hexadecimal notes can represent up to 255 which is the size of the wide ASCII table)
    sprintf(hex_arr[i], "%x", (uint8_t)arr[i]); //as arr is your integer array
}
```

Note that you can also organize everything unto one string (`char*`) where every character in spot of `i` in the integer array would be represented by two characters: `xArr[i*2]` and `xArr[i*2+1]`

Cheers.

Comment: `arr[i]` is dangerous as it may return values outside 0 - 255.  Suggest `(uint8_t) arr[i]` or `arr[i] && 255u`.

Comment: How to check if it work properly, just write printf("%x",arr[i])?

Comment: @PosticaÐenis Yes, that'll do it.